# Error while deploying spring application to Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jodatime, weblogic12c

We had weblogic 10 and was working fine with everything. We upgraded to Weblogic 12c and when trying to deploy the apps, getting error,

```
        java.io.IOException: Resource not found: "org/joda/time/tz/data/Etc/GMT+1" 
    ClassLoader: weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader@1f901fe8 finder:
 weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@1f90228d annotation: app-ear@app
```

have no idea, what exactly happening, but by seeing that, can think of timezone class file cannot load. BUt, everything looks fine when I check in the ear folder,

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add `weblogic-application.xml` configuration file to your `ear` to

```
*.ear/META-INF/weblogic-application.xml
```

With next content:

```
<wls:weblogic-application 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/j2ee_1_4.xsd 
   http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-application.xsd"> 
   <wls:prefer-application-packages>
      <wls:package-name>org.joda.*</wls:package-name>
   </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

Now `joda-time` lib from your `ear` will be used instead of `weblogic's` `joda-time` library.
Also you should have `joda-time` library in your `ear` in

```
*.ear/lib/joda-time-X.X.jar
```

Comment: I do have all the above mentioned in place but still it fails